# How to set the max requests that the snmp agent can respond in 1 min.

Tags: request, numbers, snmp, traffic, threshold

i want to restrict the number of requests that SNMP agent accepts in 1 min.
for example , the SNMP agent can respond the requests from different management station, and i want to set the max number of the requests in 1 min. if in 1 min, the agent gets more than 100 request, it will drop the request or give some information back to management station, such as "it too many request". 
i want to deal with it because i want to save the resource of CPU, when the agent get too many request in small period of time , which will lead to the pressure to the cpu.
please give me some advice

Comment: From the lack of responses you can guess that your question is too vague. Are you asking about a firewall question? Is this your own agent that you are coding? What have you tried? Etc. Please give more details, ie. at least answers to my questions.

Comment: i want to limit the number of external request to agent, the purpose is to reduce the burden of the system. my question is how should i do on the agent to limit the received request number

Answer (score 0):

This is out of scope of the SNMP standards. The answer would depend entirely on the agent you're using, the language it's implemented, etc. You would not be able to return "too many requests" in any generic way that would be understood by all managers, but you could return error-status genErr. If your goal is to harden against DoS attacks, it might be better to simply drop requests that you can't handle in a timely manner as it may well be that your agent's being used to DoS someone **else** with forged source addresses. If you're not being DoS'ed, a well behaved manager will wait and retry if the request is dropped. It also seems to me this would be better handled by using appropriate traffic-limiting ACLs in a smart switch that the device with the agent is plugged into, and not in any agent.